# titanium start and stop sound

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have this working in Javascript but can't seem to get it working on Titanium.

Here is the code:

```
var index = 0;
var i = 0;

// Filename
var wordSoundArray = [];

wordSoundArray.push('audio/the.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/of.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/and.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/a.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/to.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/in.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/is.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/you.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/that.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/it.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/he.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/was.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/for.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/on.mp3');
wordSoundArray.push('audio/are.mp3');

newWordBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    wordLabel.text = newWordArray[i++];
    if (i === newWordArray.length)
            i = 0;

    var snd = Titanium.Media.createSound({url:wordSoundArray[index++]});
    if (index === wordSoundArray.length)
            index = 0;
    if (snd.isPlaying()) {
        snd.stop();
        snd.play();
    } else {
        snd.play();
    }


});
```

When a user presses the button they get a new word and the sound that goes with that word. However, if the user presses the button before the sound is finished it simply starts the new sound and they overlap each other. That is where the snd.isPlaying portion of the code of the code comes in. I'm pretty sure my mistake is in there.

Comment: The code seems incomplete, where is variable `i` coming from? Is this in a loop?

Comment: I updated the code to include the variable statements and the array that I'm having the issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you actually have dead code here:

```
var snd = Titanium.Media.createSound({url:wordSoundArray[index++]}));
...
// You just created the sound, so it will never be playing right off the bat
if (snd.isPlaying()) { 
    // This will never be called
    snd.stop();
    snd.play();
} else {
    // This will happen every time the user clicks the button
    snd.play();
}
```

I think its good practice to pre-load all your sound assets before you start execution, so maybe try replacing your `wordSoundArray` with entries of the form:

```
wordSoundArray.push(Titanium.Media.createSound({url:'audio/the.mp3'});
```

Once you have done this (all our sound assets are preloaded, this will be good for memory too) we can change the listener to something like this:

```
newWordBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    wordLabel.text = newWordArray[i++];
    if (i === newWordArray.length)
            i = 0;

    // Instead of creating the sound, just fetch it!
    var snd = wordSoundArray[index++];

    if (index === wordSoundArray.length)
            index = 0;
    // Now this will work, but maybe you want to make sure all the sounds are off instead?
    if (snd.isPlaying()) {
        snd.stop();
        snd.play();
    } else {
        snd.play();
    }
});
```

Looking at your code though, it appears you want to stop the previous sound playing and then start the next one, so you would need to change the listener to this:

```
newWordBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    wordLabel.text = newWordArray[i++];
    if (i === newWordArray.length)
            i = 0;
    // Stop the last sound from playing
    if(index > 0) {
            var lastSound = wordSoundArray[index-1];
            lastSound.stop();
    }

    // Instead of creating the sound, just fetch it!
    var nextSound = wordSoundArray[index++];

    if (index === wordSoundArray.length)
            index = 0;
    // Play the next sound
    nextSound.play();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! I have been working on this all day. I searched through everything but only pieces helped here and there. Learned even more though. :)